# Evolution of Relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, philosophy

In Frege, one finds relations treated as predicates in complex terms. However, modern set theory appears to treat them as two-place relation. Is this correct? If so, when did this shift occur and to whom is it attributed? And, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Gottlob Frege](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/)'s mature thougth, the basic analysis of language is based on *functions* and *objects*; see Gottlob Frege, [Philosophical Writings](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C7SBRB4) (Geach & Black edition - 1952) : [Function and Concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_and_concept) (Über Funktion und Begriff - 1891), page 21-on.

He start his analysis from the "typical" mathematical fuctions, like :

> $x + 1$

which get a number as "input" and produce as "output" a number, but then he generalize them to *concepts*, i.e. functions from objects to truth-value, like :

> $x > 1$.

In this setting, a binary *relation* is a function from objects to truth-value with two argument places, like :

> $x > y$.

See page 39 :

> We have here a function whose value is always a truth-value. We called such functions of one argument concepts; we call such functions of two arguments relations.

In modern mathematical logic, the *first-order* language is based on *individual variables* and *predicate* letters.

An (atomic) expression is : $R(x,y)$, where $R$ is a binary predicate letter. In the language of arithmetic, we can use instead of the predicate letter $R$ the symbol ">" standing for the (binary) relation "greater than"; thus, we have the expression : $x > y$.

The basic difference between modern semantic for a first-order language an that of Frege is that today an expression like $x > y$ it is not interpreted as a function from couples of objects to truth-value but as the set of all couples satisying the relation.

If $\mathbb N$ is set of natural numbers which is the domain of our interpretation, we have that, writing $R^N$ for the interpretation of $R$, in the standard mathematical logic semantics :

> $>^N \subseteq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$

while for Frege :

> $>^N : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \rightarrow \{ TRUE, FALSE \}$.

The "shift" occurred progressively; already in Alfred North Whitehead and Bertrand Russell, [Principia Mathematica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica) (1910-1927) *relations* was a primitive notion (and *functions* only "special" relations : the "functional" ones).

In 1914 [Norbert Wiener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norbert_Wiener) (*A Simplification of the logic of relations*) and in 1921 [Kazimierz Kuratowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazimierz_Kuratowski) (*Sur la notion de l'ordre dans la Théorie des Ensembles*) find a way to define in the language of set theory the concept of [ordered pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_couple) thus reducing the notion of relation to that of set.

Thus, simplifying a lot, while for Frege a *relation* was a kind of *function*, in current mathematical logic a function is a type of relation which, in turn, is a special kind of *set* (which, for Frege, was the *extension* of a *concept*).